# ConvertTo-HTML parameter is not working well

Tags: powershell

I am trying to script a PowerShell file to analyze Exchange config using this CMD command:

```
PowerShell.exe -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; . 'C:\test2.ps1' | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File -FilePath C:\test.html"
```

`Test2.ps1` code:

```
Write-Output "Test"
Get-SenderIDConfig | fl -Property Enabled
Get-SenderReputationConfig | fl -Property SenderBlockingEnabled
Write-Output "List All SendConnectors"
Get-SendConnector
Write-Output "Ignoe STARTTLS SendConnectors"
Get-SendConnector | fl -Property IgnoreSTARTTLS
```

The output works fine by directly redirecting it to a TXT file (`>> output.txt`) but the problem is that I get a non-readable output using `ConvertTo-HTML`, like in this picture:

[image]

Edit : this is the wanted result

[image]

Comment: `ConvertTo-Html` is working just fine. It simply doesn't do what you expect. The cmdlet transforms the input objects to tables where the object properties become the table columns. String objects have only one property: `Length`, so your `Write-Output` values become numbers in the output (the respective string lengths). `Format-List` generates formatting objects. Only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets for displaying data directly to a user. In all other cases use `Select-Object` instead. And if cmdlet output has nested objects you need to expand those yourself.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers for the explanation, What do you recommend to get the best display for the script ? the script will have more than +50 commands, so it should look clear and organized

Comment: What do you expect me to recommend? I have no idea what data you want to present, and to whom.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Check the post .. i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass input like that to `ConvertTo-Html` and expect the cmdlet to magically produce a report in the desired format. The cmdlet doesn't work that way. It's normally used for converting a list of objects of the same type to tabular output, e.g. you can take the output of `Get-SendConnector` and make an HTML table from that:

```
Get-SendConnector | Select-Object Identity, AddressSpaces, Enabled | ConvertTo-Html
```

However, that by itself will create a complete HTML page. Since you want other (non-tabular) data in the page as well, you can create the table as a *fragment*, and insert that and the other data into a string template, e.g. like this:

```
$head = @'
<style>
/* put style definitions here */
h1 { font-size: 20px; }
h2 { font-size: 16px; }
/* ... */
</style>
'@

$fragments = @()
$fragments += '<p>Enabled: {0}</p>' -f (Get-SenderIDConfig).Enabled
$fragments += '<p>SenderBlockingEnabled: {0}</p>' -f (Get-SenderReputationConfig).SenderBlockingEnabled
$fragments += Get-SendConnector |
              Select-Object Identity, AddressSpaces, Enabled |
              ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>List All SendConnectors</h2>'
$fragments += Get-SendConnector |
              Select-Object Identity, IgnoreSTARTTLS |
              ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Ignore STARTTLS Connectory</h2>'

ConvertTo-Html -Head $head -PreContent '<h1>Test</h1>' -PostContent $fragments |
    Set-Content 'output.html'
```

See [this *Scripting Guy* article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/01/working-with-html-fragments-and-files/) for more information.

You could also build your own HTML template and fill that with values:

```
$template = @'
<html>
<head>
<style>...</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enabled: {0}</p>
<p>SenderBlockingEnabled: {1}</p>
{2}
{3}
</body>
</html>
'@

$enabled         = (Get-SenderIDConfig).Enabled
$blockingEnabled = (Get-SenderReputationConfig).SenderBlockingEnabled
$connectors      = Get-SendConnector |
                   Select-Object Identity, AddressSpaces, Enabled |
                   ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>List All SendConnectors</h2>' |
                   Out-String
$ignoreSTARTTLS  = Get-SendConnector |
                   Select-Object Identity, IgnoreSTARTTLS |
                   ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Ignore STARTTLS Connectory</h2>' |
                   Out-String

$template -f $enabled, $blockingEnabled, $connectors, $ignoreSTARTTLS |
    Set-Content 'output.html'
```